# 256 Colors in Amazon AMI SSH Session

Tags: shell, vim, amazon-ec2, 256color

I have a few ec2 instances of the Amazon linux ami (`amzn-ami-pv-2013.09.2.x86_64-ebs`) which I ssh into for python development in vim. I'd like to begin using some of the 256 color themes like blackboard or codeschool, but am having trouble getting a 256 color terminal. I'm ssh'ing in from Mac OSX.

A few notes:

- running `tput colors` from the shell returns `256`
- `echo $TERM` returns `xterm-256color`
- however, running scripts like http://www.robmeerman.co.uk/_media/unix/256colors2.pl reveal that only 16 colors are available

I've tried the suggestions found pages like this one (and many others):
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/256_colors_in_vim

But haven't gotten the terminal itself to correctly display 256 colors. I'd like to use screen with 256 colors too, but need to get the terminal working correctly first.

Is anyone else running into this with the Amazon AMIs?

Thanks a bunch!

UPDATE: I can see 256 colors when ssh'ing via putty from my Windows box. This might be a function of the Mac OSX shell.

Comment: You don't need to do anything on your remote host. Both iTerm and Terminal support 256 colors so set them up correctly.

Comment: originally, my remote host had `TERM=xterm` by default. i needed to update that in my `~/.bashrc` file to `TERM=xterm-256color`.

Comment: That was bad configuration, then. `TERM` tells your shell and the programs that you run in your shell what your terminal emulator can and can't do. Setting it in `~.bashrc` makes no sense unless you routinely use a terminal emulator that doesn't let you set `TERM` directly and in that case it should be set in a conditional to avoid the kind of problem you experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using iTerm2?

http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home

It supports 256 colors:

http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/features/256_colors

Answer (score 0):

Your client is probably fine. You probably need to tweak your AWS instance.
There are a couple of links from this section to describe that:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/256_Color_Terminals#Adjusting_the_remote_system_to_support_256_colors